# cannot choose options confirm with bootbox

Tags: bootbox

i have a button that i use to delete records
every time bootbox shows the confirm its closes automatically
here in the example the "cancel" button does not word
where is the mistake?

```js
        function ConfermaCancella()
        {
           // e.preventDefault();
            bootbox.confirm("Sure to delete?", function (result) {

                if (result) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://bootboxjs.com/bootbox.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick = "return ConfermaCancella();" ID="ImageButton3"  value="Delete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-notes):

> All Bootstrap modals, unlike native alerts, confirms, or prompts,
>   generate non-blocking events. Because of this limitation, code that
>   should not be evaluated until a user has dismissed your dialog should
>   be placed (or called) within the callback function of the dialog.

So, if you want something to happen only if the user confirms the action, you need to move your code into a callback, like so:

```
function ConfermaCancella(){

    bootbox.confirm('Confirm delete?', function(result){

        /* 'result' is a truthy value */

        if(result){
            /* Do your delete action, probably using AJAX actions */
        }

    });

    return false;
}
```